# how to deactivate twitter account in iPhone app that used for Integration

Tags: objective-c, twitter, slrequest

I have app where I am doing the Twitter integration.

I am able to successfully tweets.

Now when I want to de-activate, I am using below.

```
SLRequest *postRequest1 = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter 
requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/end_session.json"] 
parameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"status"]];
```

Problem is API with 1 is deprecated and I don't find this method in 1.1.

Is there any alternate for this?

Also what I notice is when I try to activate again, the permission is not asked. It directly send tweet. **It ask tweet permission for the first time only. Not after de-activate -- Re-activate process.** Is this is how Twitter behaves?

### Edit 1

Code I use for all tweet is as below...

```
if ([self userHasAccessToTwitter]) {

    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];


    // Request access from the user to access their Twitter account
    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted == YES)
         {

             ///////////////////////////////////////////////
             //           SEND TEXT ONLY                 ///
             ///////////////////////////////////////////////
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"twitterLogin"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


             // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
             NSString *message1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi! I am using twitter integration."];
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 //use the first account available
                 ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

                 SLRequest *postRequest1 = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message1 forKey:@"status"]];
                 [postRequest1 setAccount:acct];//set account
                 [postRequest1 performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                     if(error) {
                         NSLog(@"error == %@", error);
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"good to go -1- %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                     }

                 }];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`end_session` in API v1 never worked as it should anyway. Starting from 1.1 this method was removed and there's no alternative method. The user should decide if he wants to revoke your application access to his twitter account. The only thing you could do is to delete the `auth_token`.

Comment: any idea how to delete auth_token

Comment: @FahimParkar When you request a token from twitter you store it in your app. Delete it from there using `_yourToken = nil;`

Comment: see my edited question... I am not saving token data in app... i am requesting everytime... any idea how to delete in my case?

Comment: You can't do that with the given API.

Comment: how should I do then? bcz this is how I am posting tweets on user wall automatically...

Comment: There's no accessible token you can delete with the native iOS API. Like I said, there's no way or need to do it, It's up to the user to revoke it.